# How can i place 1 to 5 images on top of another image?

Tags: html, css

As a user of a program selectes from one to five images, i want these images to be placed on top of another image as seen below. The image in the background is one long image in light gray, and the one to five on top are in black.

[image: one image selected]

when i add any any ONE of the five images, the image on top is placed correctly
[image]

But when i select more than one image, the position of the 2-3-4-5 image is not correct:
[image: When more than one image is selected, the first one is placed correctly, while the other images get placed wrongly.]

This is my code, and the images are placed in a html table cell

```
<td><img src="backgroundimg.gif">
<img src="img1.gif" style="right:333;position:relative;z-index: 1;">
<img src="img2.gif" style="right:214;position:relative;z-index: 1;">
<img src="img2.gif" style="right:154;position:relative;z-index: 1;">
<img src="img2.gif" style="right:95;position:relative;z-index: 1;">
</td>
```

I dont have access to the css files, so the css have to be inline....
Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is not really clear.  Can you provide a working snippet of what you have and a better explanation of what you want?

Comment: Ill try: The user of a program select one to six options (checkboxes), either one, or all six, and then a html code is generated where the users choices are displayed as black images on top of the grey "background" image as a way to show the users the choices made in a graphical way. What i think happens now, is that the first image is placed correctly, but the latter images are placed in in relation to the first black image causing them to appear on the wrong places....

Comment: something like greyed out images and when clicked on they turn darker? Or do you have two sets of images both start greyed out and when the top images are clicked on the bottom images get darker? or do you have just 6 checkboxes and when they are checked an image of all images appear but the checked ones are darker?

Comment: when no checkbox is check, it will show only the grey out image. As users check the boxes, new images will appear that are placed on top of the grey out image. These are smaller images that are black.
I thank you for your patience :)

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  can you use js?

Comment: I think so, i can add <script></script>

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('div').removeClass("grey100");
    } else {
        $('div').addClass("grey100");
    }
});
```

```css
.grey100 {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
       -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
         -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
            filter: grayscale(100%); 
            
            opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='grey100'>
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/rss81/image/upload/gw.jpg">
<input type="checkbox" > 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and i now understand where i was unclear. Im sorry for that. I have a python gui where my text writers type product texts and that generates a html code that is used on my website. When the html code is genererated it checks if the checkboxes are checked and if they are, the small black images are placed on top of the grey one. Each black image has to have an absolute location based on the grey image as the site is responsive. As of now, if one box is checked the black image is placed correctly, but if more than one is checked. The latter black images are placed wrong

Comment: why not just change the opacity of the image, doesn't that do the same thing without having to download and overlay images?

Comment: That could work, Im open to try everything. As of now it seems that the image from the first black image in the code is placed correctly, but the latter images are placing themself somehow related to the first image. I could also add a singel image for every possible option, but as the user can select 1-2-3-4 or 5 images in any order or number, it would create a lot of, what i think is, unnecessary code. How can i solve it with ocpacity?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and see if it's what you're looking for:

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('img').toggleClass("grey100");
});
```

```css
.grey100 {
    
            opacity: 0.5;
}

img{
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div >
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <img class='grey100'src="https://res.cloudinary.com/rss81/image/upload/gw.jpg"><br>
            <input type="checkbox"  >
         </td>
         <td >
            <img class='grey100'src="https://res.cloudinary.com/rss81/image/upload/gw.jpg"><br>
            <input type="checkbox"   >
         </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```