# jQuery to gray-out images

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I am using jQuery to limit the number of checkboxes, attached to images, able to be selected by customers and I would like to gray-out the rest of the images once a certain number of checkboxes are selected. I've done this so far in jQuery but if Vanilla JS for this portion is quicker I can use that as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm also looking into the .fadeTo() function as well in the jQuery documentation:

Comment: I have been researching this, this is the documentation used: https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ and I've also been through YouTube and stackoverflow looking for the correct way to do this.

Comment: Let's see some jQuery code and CSS.  Here's some code to get you thinking more about code and less about English. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44875211/3825777

Comment: If you can provide an example of your code you have to so far it would help in providing a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to gray-out an image, you can use the [`grayscale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale()) filter. Here's an example using JQuery. Because the filter is part of a class, you can set the class on any number of images (like the ones that you no longer want the user to select).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let myButton = $('#myButton');
  let myImage = $('#myImage');

  myButton.on('click', function() {
    if (myImage.hasClass('inactive'))
    {
      myImage.removeClass('inactive');
      myButton.attr('value', 'Disable image');
    }
    else 
    {
      myImage.addClass('inactive');
      myButton.attr('value', 'Enable image');
    } 
  });
});
```

```css
img.inactive {
  filter: grayscale(100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="myImage" alt="Alexander the Great" width=100 src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Alexander_the_Great%2C_from_Alexandria%2C_Egypt%2C_3rd_cent._BCE%2C_Ny_Carlsberg_Glyptotek%2C_Copenhagen_%285%29_%2836375553176%29.jpg/800px-Alexander_the_Great%2C_from_Alexandria%2C_Egypt%2C_3rd_cent._BCE%2C_Ny_Carlsberg_Glyptotek%2C_Copenhagen_%285%29_%2836375553176%29.jpg">
<br>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="Disable image">
```

Comment: I like this, I'm looking to make it so that the user can select 3 images and the rest will fade out and if they unselect an image the images will fade in

Comment: So I've come up with something like this to kind of give an idea of what I'm going for: if(max){$('input_1.').fadeTo('fast', 0.3)}else{$('input_1.').fadeTo('fast', 1)}; but I'm getting an uncaught error in the browser as I test it and I'm not sure why yet

Comment: `input_1.` is not a valid selector.

Comment: I got it working! Thank you for the help!!! You were right, the selector was way off!